# Offset Array function result to the left by 3 columns

Tags: excel, offset

I have a table which has the recent buy sell values of the products and Iam trying to consolidate the action of buy/sell basis expiry dates of the products with the top3 buy and sell prices in different tables.

I was able to arrive at the highest value basis the conditions I want, but unable to find a way to offset the array formula to the left by 2 columns to find the buy price basis the total outstanding amount.

```
=LARGE(IF((B:B=$K$3)*(C:C=$L$4)*(E:E="Buy"),F:F),1)
```

Iam unable to find away offset the result of the large functions by 2 columns to find the respective buy price.

Comment: `XLOOKUP` or `INDEX`+`MATCH` or `FILTER`.